# How to write a macro to copy date or filename column next to the copied data

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro to open filepaths specified in cells A1:A4 in Sheet1 of a template file and copy/paste the data from the opened workbook to Sheet2 of the template.

The problem is because I am stacking data from multiple files, I would like to insert the date for each next to the data, in for eg. column A.

The cells B1:B4 in Sheet1 has the dates.

So the end result should be something like:

```
01/01/2017     Apple     Orange     Pear
```

Is this possible?

My code attempt:

```
Sheets("Macro").Select
Range("C6").Select 
Application.CutCopyMode = False 
Selection.Copy 
Sheets("Actual").Select 
Range("D2:D18").Select 
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ 
:=False, Transpose:=False
```

The problem is the copied data will be varying rows and the D2:D18 is bit is static.

Comment: It is definitely possible, have you tried to record a macro while doing this manually and check out the auto-generated code to get a starting point?

Comment: Sheets("Macro").Select                                                            .    Range("C6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Actual").Select
Range("D2:D18").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False                                                         The problem is the copied data will be varying rows and the D2:D18 is bit is static.

Comment: Your code should go in the question: typically too difficult to make sense of in a comment.